# Register a texture array from OpenGL to CUDA

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop

I want to register a texture array created with OpenGL to CUDA. For that I simply use the interoperability function `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` (see [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d)) :

```cpp
void registerTextureInCUDA()
{
     // _textureDepth = 2 here
     GLenum target = _textureDepth < 2 ? GL_TEXTURE_2D : GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY;

     GLuint texture = 0;

     GLsizei width = 2;
     GLsizei height = 2;
     GLsizei layerCount = 2;
     GLsizei mipLevelCount = 1;

     // Read you texels here. In the current example, we have 2*2*2 = 8 texels, with each texel being 4 GLubytes.
     GLubyte texels[32] = 
     {
          // Texels for first image.
          0,   0,   0,   255,
          255, 0,   0,   255,
          0,   255, 0,   255,
          0,   0,   255, 255,
          // Texels for second image.
          255, 255, 255, 255,
          255, 255,   0, 255,
          0,   255, 255, 255,
          255, 0,   255, 255,
     };

     glGenTextures(1,&texture);
     glBindTexture(target,texture);

     // No error after this call
     GL_CHECK();
     
     CUDA_CHECK(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&_pGraphicsResource, texture, target, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard));
}
```

For simple `GL_TEXTURE_2D` I have no error and I can write into the texture normally, but with `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` I have the following error :

```
Cuda error: 1 invalid argument
```

In [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d) this type of return does not seem to be expected ?
What argument could be in cause here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I didn't allocate the storage for the texture, I just need to add this line before registering the texture in cuda :

`glTexStorage3D(target, mipLevelCount, GL_RGBA8, width, height, layerCount);`